# Upper bound for $\mathbb{P}(|X-\mathbb{E}(X)|\geq t)$ for $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I found the following bound for $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$:

$$\mathbb{P}(X-\mu\geq t) \leq \exp\left(-\frac{t^2}{2\sigma^2}\right).$$
$$\mathbb{P}(|X-\mu|\geq t) \leq 2 \exp\left(-\frac{t^2}{2\sigma^2}\right).$$

Do you know if this bound has a name? I use it in my thesis and I need name or some kind of source. I didn't found any unfortunately, so maybe you can help me. (I do not need a proof.)

Comment: These tail bounds are direct consequences of Chebyshev's inequality. You can refer to some statistics textbook, or refer to Chebyshev's inequality and just prove the result.

Comment: Okay, I'll just prove it myself

Comment: @PierreCarre Isn't it a direct consequence of the Chernoff bound instead of Chebyshev?